# Reliable and effective custom search & replace function - preg or str replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In a few different guises I've asked about this "filter" on here and WPSE. I'm now taking a different approach to it, and I'd like to make it solid and reliable.

My situation:

- When I create a post in my WordPress CMS, I want to run a filter which searches for certain terms and replaces them with links.
- I have the terms that I want to search for in two arrays: `$glossary_terms` and `$species_terms`.
- `$species_terms` is a list of scientific names of fishes, such as `Apistogramma panduro`.
- `$glossary_terms` is a list of fishkeeping glossary terms such as `abdomen`, `caudal-fin` and `Gram's Method`.

There are a few nuances worth noting:

- Speed is *not* an issue, as I will be running this filter *in the background* rather than when a user visits the page or whan an author submits/edits a species profile or post.
- Some of the post content being filtered may contain HTML with these terms in, like `<img src="image.jpg" title="Apistogramma panduro male" />`. Obviously these shouldn't be replaced.
- Species are often referred to with an abbreviated Genus, so instead of `Apistogramma panduro`, you'll often see `A. panduro`. This means I need to search & replace all of the species terms as an abbreviation too - `Apistogramma panduro`, `A. panduro`, `Satanoperca daemon`, `S. daemon` etc.
- If `caudal-fin` and `caudal` both exist in the glossary terms, `caudal-fin` should be replaced first.

I was contemplating simply adding a `preg_replace` which searched for the terms, but only with a space on the left, (i.e. `( )term`) and a space, comma, exclamation, full-stop or hyphen on the right (i.e. `term(, . ! - )`) but that won't help me to not break the image HTML.

---

**Example content**

```
<br />
It looks very similar to fishes of the <i><a href="species/betta-foerschi" rel="species/betta-foerschi/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. foerschi</a></i> group/complex but its breeding strategy, adult size and observed behaviour preclude its inclusion in that <a href="glossary/a/assemblage" rel="glossary/a/assemblage?hover=true" class="link_glossary">assemblage</a>.

Instead it appears to be a member of the <i><a href="species/betta-coccina" rel="species/betta-coccina/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. coccina</a></i> group which currently includes <i><a href="species/betta-brownorum" rel="species/betta-brownorum/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. brownorum</a></i>, <i><a href="species/betta-burdigala" rel="species/betta-burdigala/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. burdigala</a></i>, <i><a href="species/betta-coccina" rel="species/betta-coccina/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. coccina</a></i>, <i><a href="species/betta-livida" rel="species/betta-livida/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. livida</a></i>, <i>B. miniopinna</i>, <i><a href="species/betta-persephone" rel="species/betta-persephone/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. persephone</a></i>, <i>B. tussyae</i>, <i><a href="species/betta-rutilans" rel="species/betta-rutilans/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. rutilans</a></i> and <i><a href="species/betta-uberis" rel="species/betta-uberis/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. uberis</a></i>.

Of these it's most similar in appearance to <i><a href="species/betta-uberis" rel="species/betta-uberis/?hover=true" class="link_species">B. uberis</a></i> but can be distinguished by its noticeably shorter <a href="glossary/d/dorsal" rel="glossary/d/dorsal?hover=true" class="link_glossary">dorsal</a>-<a href="glossary/f/fin" rel="glossary/f/fin?hover=true" class="link_glossary">fin</a> <a href="glossary/b/base" rel="glossary/b/base?hover=true" class="link_glossary">base</a> and overall blue-greenish (vs. green/reddish) colouration.

Members of this group are characterised by their small adult size (&lt; 40 mm SL), a uniform red or black <a href="glossary/b/base" rel="glossary/b/base?hover=true" class="link_glossary">base</a> body colour, the presence of a <a href="glossary/m/midlateral" rel="glossary/m/midlateral?hover=true" class="link_glossary">midlateral</a> body blotch in some <a href="glossary/s/species" rel="glossary/s/species?hover=true" class="link_glossary">species</a> and the fact they have 9 abdominal <a href="glossary/v/vertebrae" rel="glossary/v/vertebrae?hover=true" class="link_glossary">vertebrae</a> compared with 10-12 in the other <a href="glossary/s/species" rel="glossary/s/species?hover=true" class="link_glossary">species</a> groups. In addition all are <a href="glossary/o/obligate" rel="glossary/o/obligate?hover=true" class="link_glossary">obligate</a> <a href="glossary/p/peat" rel="glossary/p/peat?hover=true" class="link_glossary">peat</a> <a href="glossary/s/swamp" rel="glossary/s/swamp?hover=true" class="link_glossary">swamp</a> dwellers (Tan and Ng, 2005).<br />
```

^^^ This example here has had the correct links manually inserted. The filter shouldn't break these links!

```
It looks very similar to fishes of the B. foerschi group/complex but its breeding strategy, adult size and observed behaviour preclude its inclusion in that assemblage.

Instead it appears to be a member of the B. coccina group which currently includes B. brownorum, B. burdigala, B. coccina, B. livida, B. miniopinna, B. persephone, B. tussyae, B. rutilans and B. uberis.

Of these it's most similar in appearance to B. uberis but can be distinguished by its noticeably shorter dorsal-fin base and overall blue-greenish (vs. green/reddish) colouration.

Members of this group are characterised by their small adult size (< 40 mm SL), a uniform red or black base body colour, the presence of a midlateral body blotch in some species and the fact they have 9 abdominal vertebrae compared with 10-12 in the other species groups. In addition all are obligate peat swamp dwellers (Tan and Ng, 2005).
```

^^^ Same example pre-formatting.

```
[caption id="attachment_542" align="alignleft" width="125" caption="Amazonas Magazine - now in English!"]<a href="http://www.seriouslyfish.comwp-content/uploads/2011/12/Amazonas-English-1.jpg"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-542" title="Amazonas English" src="/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Amazonas-English-1-288x381.jpg" alt="Amazonas English" width="125" height="165" /></a>[/caption]

Edited by Hans-Georg Evers, the magazine 'Amazonas' has been widely-regarded as among the finest regular publications in the hobby since its launch in 2005, an impressive achievment considering it's only been published in German to date. The long-awaited English version is just about to launch, and we think a subscription should be top of any serious fishkeeper's Xmas list...

The magazine is published in a bi-monthly basis and the English version launches with the January/February 2012 issue with distributors already organised in the United States, Canada, the United Kingdom, South Africa, Australia, and New Zealand. There are also mobile apps availablen which allow digital subscribers to read on portable devices.

It's fair to say that there currently exists no better publication for dedicated hobbyists with each issue featuring cutting-edge articles on fishes, invertebrates, aquatic plants, field trips to tropical destinations plus the latest in husbandry and breeding breakthroughs by expert aquarists, all accompanied by excellent photography throughout.

U.S. residents can subscribe to the printed edition for just $29 USD per year, which also includes a free digital subscription, with the same offer available to Canadian readers for $41 USD or overseas subscribers for $49 USD. Please see the <a href="http://www.amazonasmagazine.com/">Amazonas website</a> for further information and a sample digital issue!

Alternatively, subscribe directly to the print version <a href="https://www.amazonascustomerservice.com/subscribe/index2.php">here</a> or digital version <a href="https://www.amazonascustomerservice.com/subscribe/digital.php">here</a>.
```

^^^ This will likely only have a few Glossary terms in rather than any species links.

---

**Example terms**

`$species_terms`

```
339 => 'Aulonocara maylandi maylandi',
340 => 'Aulonocara maylandi kandeensis',
341 => 'Aulonocara sp. "walteri"',
342 => 'Aulonocara sp. "stuartgranti maleri"',
343 => 'Aulonocara stuartgranti',
344 => 'Benthochromis tricoti',
345 => 'Boulengerochromis microlepis',
346 => 'Buccochromis lepturus',
347 => 'Buccochromis nototaenia',
348 => 'Betta brownorum',
349 => 'Betta foerschi',
350 => 'Betta coccina',
351 => 'Betta uberis'
```

As you can see above, the general format for these scientific names is "Genus species", but can often include "sp." or "aff." (for species which aren't officially described) and "Genus species subspecies" formats.

`$glossary_terms`

```
1 => 'abdomen',
2 => 'caudal',
3 => 'caudal-fin',
4 => 'caudal-fin peduncle',
5 => 'Gram\'s Method'
```

If anyone can come up with a filter which meets all these conditions and requirements, I'd like to offer a bounty.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just a thought. Would it be possible to first 'extract' all `<a></a>` using preg_replace_callback and replacing each `<a></a>` with a unique identifier. After that you can run your own preg_replace. Afterwards replace each unique link with its respective content. Voila?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's better to use [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) functionality than regexps. Here is a working prototype:

```
// Each dynamically constructed regexp will contain at most 70 subpatterns
define('GROUPS_PER_REGEXPS', 70);

$speciesTerms = array(
  339 => '(?:Aulonocara|A\.) maylandi maylandi',
  340 => '(?:Aulonocara|A\.) maylandi kandeensis',
  344 => '(?:Benthochromis|B\.) tricoti',
  345 => '(?:Boulengerochromis|B\.) microlepis',
);

function matchTerms($text) {
  // Globals are not good. I left it for the simplicity
  global $speciesTerms;

  $result = array();
  $t = 0;
  $speciesCount = count($speciesTerms);
  reset($speciesTerms);
  while ($t < $speciesCount) {
    // Maps capturing group identifiers to term ids
    $termMapping = array();

    // Dynamically construct regexp
    $groups = '';
    $c = 1;
    while (list($termId, $termPattern) = each($speciesTerms)) {
      if (!empty($groups)) {
        $groups .= '|';
      }
      // Match word boundaries, so we don't capture "B. tricotisomeramblingstring"
      $groups .= '(\b' . $termPattern . '\b)';
      $termMapping[$c++] = $termId;
      if (++$t % GROUPS_PER_REGEXPS == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
    $regexp = "/$groups/m";
    preg_match_all($regexp, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $c; $i++) {
      foreach ($matches[$i] as $matchData) {
        // matchData[0] holds matched string, e.g. Benthochromis tricoti
        // matchData[1] holds offset, e.g. 15
        if (isset($matchData[0]) && !empty($matchData[0])) {
          $result[] = array(
            'text' => $matchData[0],
            'offset' => $matchData[1],
            'id' => $termMapping[$i],
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Sort by offset in descending order
  usort($result, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['offset'] > $b['offset'] ? -1 : 1;
  });
  return $result;
}

$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

// Stack will be used to avoid recursive functions
$stack = new SplStack;
$stack->push($doc);
while (!$stack->isEmpty()) {
  $node = $stack->pop();
  if ($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE && $node->parentNode instanceof DOMElement) {
    // $node represents text node
    //  and it's inside a tag (second condition in the statement above)

    // Check that this text is not wrapped in <a> tag
    //  as we don't want to wrap it twice
    if ($node->parentNode->tagName != 'a') {
      $matches = matchTerms($node->wholeText);
      foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // Create new link element in the DOM
        $link = $doc->createElement('a', $match['text']);
        $link->setAttribute('href', 'species/' . $match['id']);
        $link->setAttribute('class', 'link_species');

        // Save the text after the link
        $remainingText = $node->splitText($match['offset'] + strlen($match['text']));
        // Save the text before the link
        $linkText = $node->splitText($match['offset']);

        // Replace $linkText with $link node
        //  i.e. 'something' becomes '<a href="..">something</a>'
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $linkText);
      }
    }
  }
  if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode) {
      $stack->push($childNode);
    }
  }
}

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
echo $doc->saveHTML($body->item(0));
```

**Implementation details**

I've only showed how to replace species terms, glossary terms will be same. Links are formed in form "species/$id". Abbreviations are handled correctly. `DOMDocument` is a very reliable parser, it can deal with broken markup and is fast.

`?:` in regexp allows not to count this subpattern as a capturing group ([documentation on subpatterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)). Without proper counting of subpatterns, we can't retrieve the `termId`. The idea is that we build a big regexp pattern by joining all regexps specified in `$speciesTerms` array and separating them with a pipe `|`. Final regexp for the first two species would be (spaces for clarity):

```
       First capturing group             Alternation       Second capturing group
( (?:Aulonocara|A\.) maylandi maylandi )      |       ( (?:Aulonocara|A\.) maylandi kandeensis )
```

So, the text "Examples: Aulonocara maylandi maylandi, A. maylandi kandeensis" will give following matches:

```
$matches[1] = array('Aulonocara maylandi maylandi') // Captured by the first group
$matches[2] = array('A. maylandi kandeensis') // Captured by the second group
```

We can clearly say that all elements in `matches[1]` are referring to the species `Aulonocara maylandi maylandi` or `A. maylandi maylandi` which has id = 339.

*In short*: Use `(?:)` if you're using subpatterns in `$speciesTerms`.

**UPDATE**
Each dynamically created regexp has a limit on maximal number of subpatterns, which is defined as a const at the top. This allows avoiding PCRE limit on number of subpatterns in regexp.

**Important notes:**

- If you have a lot of terms you should rewrite `matchTerms`, because regexp has a limit on a number of subpatterns. In this case it's optimal to prebuild array of regexps out of every N terms.
- `matchTerms` generates regexp at every call, obviously it can be done only once
- It's possible to use advanced regexps in `speciesTerms`
- `strlen` => `mb_strlen` if you're using multibyte encodings
- Supplied `$html` will be wrapped in a `<body>` tag (unless it's already wrapped)

Comment: Fantastic response, thanks. I'm going to try to implement it now, though I'm somewhat concerned that it's too complex for me to debug if it doesn't work! What does the `(?:` before the species terms do?

Comment: @dunc Yeah, it looks like a lot of code, but it gives you a great flexibility. Also, the matching code (`matchTerms`) can be tested separately from replacing code (manipulations with `DOMDocument`). This means it'll be easier to debug and test

Comment: Hi @galymzhan, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, thanks to 1360 species names, I'm getting the following error: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 34743 in /dunc/test.php on line 14`. Is there anything that can be done to optimise the expression? I've tried increasing the necessary pcre settings with `ini_set` but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I've added the regexp here: http://pastebin.com/aEA8YcKy in case you'd like to test it. There's a chance that my functions aren't working properly I guess, but I suspect it might just be the pure size of the regexp itself.

Comment: @dunc Probably code hit limit on subpatterns. I've added a simple example on how to limit number of subpatterns. See if that helps

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to parse the HTML rather than trying to use regular expressions.  Regex is good when you have something specific you want to match, but gets quirky when you're trying to NOT match certain things.

Using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ :

```
function addLinks(&$p, $species, $terms) {

  // much easier to say "not in an anchor tag" with parsed content than with regex
  if ($p->tag != 'a') {

    // pull out existing elements so they aren't replaced
    $children = array();
    $x = 0;

    foreach ($p->children as &$e) {
      $children[] = $e->outertext;
      $e->outertext = '---child-'.$x.'---';
      $x++;
    }

    foreach($species as $s) {
      $p->innertext = str_replace(
          $s,
          '<a href="species/'.strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$s)).'">'.$s.'</a>',
          $p->innertext);
    }

    foreach($term as $t) {
      $p->innertext = str_replace(
          $t,
          '<a href="glossary/'.
              strtolower($t[0]).'/'.
              strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$t)).'">'.$t.'</a>',
          $p->innertext);
    }

    // restore previous child elements
    foreach($children as $x => $e) {
      $p->innertext = str_replace('---child-'.$x.'---', $e, $p->innertext);
    }

    foreach ($p->children() as &$e) {
      addLinks($e, $species, $terms);
    }
  }
}


$html = new simple_html_dom();

// you may have to wrap $content in a div. not exactly sure how partial content is handled
$html->load($content);

addLinks($html, $species_terms, $glossary_terms);
$content = $html->save();
```

I haven't used simple_html_dom a whole lot, but that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I realized replacing innertext would probably give the same problem with existing anchor tags and images, so I added something to pull out and then restore existing child elements so they aren't affected by the replace on the parent.

Comment: I understood what you were doing until those changes! :) Could you explain exactly how that works?

Comment: $p->innertext may return 'this is some text and here is <a href="">a link</a> that is inside of it'.  So the str_replace will still catch the text inside that anchor and double link it.  The changes I added temporarily remove any child elements, do the replaces, and then add them back. I'll try to actually test that it does what I think if I get a chance.